# MS Visual Studio IDE tip

Tags: c#

As a java developer, I am required to work on C# .

I am familiar with Eclipse IDE. In the MS Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, how to do the similar  ?

1. If I use F12 to see the difinition, then how can I go back to the original file ?
2. For an interface, how can I see all classes implementing this interface or method ? In the Eclipse, we just use CTRL+K.

Comment: [Keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576362.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) If your mouse has a "Back" thumb button, you can typically use that to navigate backwards. Otherwise, bind a keyboard shortcut to "View.NavigateBackward" (Edit: The default key binding is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>). Or click this button:

[image]

2) This isn't possible without an extension of some kind, Visual Studio doesn't support this out of the box. The best you could do is "Find All References" on the interface, and the results of that should include every class that implements that interface.

Comment: In addition to Point 1, there is also a Navigate Backwards (and forwards) button on the IDE toolbar.

Comment: And the default C# binding to it is `Ctrl -`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure for the second request however:

1. `CTRL+-` go back to the previous position
2. `CTRL+K, R` find all references

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click, "Go to Definition"
2. Not supported, because it's a bad feature that leads to bugs. You shouldn't use it. The reason? It's likely that important projects that have types that implement an interface will not be loaded, and so this would lead to a false sense that you've touched every implementer.  Most of the time when you want to do this, you're looking the wrong direction up your inheritance tree.

Comment: #1 is not what he was asking. He wants to go back *after* he goes to a definition.

Answer (score 0):

After hitting F12 and naviating to the function definition, you can use Ctrl+TabKey to go back the source file.

Moreover, for a detailed list of keyboard shortcuts of VS 2010 see this [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, F12 will take you to the definition...where as Ctrl + - (minus) ....will take you back to where you were before...

As other ppl mentioned the second case is not supported...
Here is a list of [Pre-Defined keyboard shorcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx) for Visual Studio 2010...that can be useful to you...